# Subdomain en relative URL's

Tags: php, html, url, subdomain, relative-path

I am working on a webapplication that's running on a subdomain. In the code I used relative URL's all over the place. Nothing special, just the normal way to go.

I have just uploaded the site, but I can't find any file that I want to include. This, for example, is working now:

```
Site URL: sub.domain.com
CSS files are in: sub.domain.com/css/

Adding the following to the index.php **is working:**
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styleSomething.css">
```

But including PHP files it the thing that is not working

```
Site URL: sub.domain.com
PHP Include files are in: sub.domain.com/inc/

Adding the following to the index.php is **not** working:
require_one(/inc/config.php)
```

If I change the URL's to start with a ./ or with no slash at all it will find the files for the homepage. But that's not going to work when the visitor navigets to a different page.

Am I missing some here of is this a problem with the hosting?

Comment: It seems from your clarified question that it probably has to do with the hosting. What is your exact domain name? In your original question you mentioned your files being placed in sub-folders - this is no longer clear from the example.

Comment: The whole site is runnning on a subdomain. All the folders/files are located in a folder structure under the subdomain. The example is still not good. CSS file are working, only PHP incluse are not working. So I can't include a file that is locatie in the same folder as the index.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<base>` tag to set the root URL for your site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

The following should work for your example:

```
<base href="http://www.blah.com/yadda1/yadda2">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleSomething.css">
```

This will reference the stylesheet at `http://www.blah.com/yadda1/yadda2/css/styleSomething.css`.

---

If you are using PHP and using several URLs, place your base URL in a variable:

```
<base href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have the pages under /rel1 under the root of the server.
If so, try using /rel1/css/style.css.